# C# int ToString format on 2 char int?

Tags: c#, tostring

How do I use the ToString method on an integer to display a 2-char

`int i = 1; i.ToString() -> "01" instead of "1"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use `i.ToString("D2")` or `i.ToString("00")`

See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-decimal-d-format-specifier) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/) for more details

Answer (score 16):

This should do it:

```
String.Format("{0:00}",i);
```

Here's a link to an msdn article on using custom formatting strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Answer (score 7):

In order to ensure at least 2 digits are displayed use the `"00"` format string.

```
i.ToString("00");
```

Here is a handy reference guide for all of the different ways numeric strings can be formatted

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Answer (score 5):

In C# 6 you could write:

```
var i = 1;
var stringI = $"{i:D2}";
```

[$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Answer (score 3):

`i.ToString("00")` Take a look at [this](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) for more rules.

Answer (score 0):

In any case you wanna check first if it's only 1 number, use Regular Expression:

```
Regex OneNumber = new Regex("^[0-9]$");
OneNumber.Replace(i.ToString(), "0" + i)
```