# Adding a 0 if number is less than 10

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# int ToString format on 2 char int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281078/c-sharp-int-tostring-format-on-2-char-int)

Sorry for the simplicity, but this one is eluding me.  Pretty much I have a list of 36 records, and if the id is less than 10, I need it to return 01, 02, 03... 09, instead of 1, 2, 3... 9.

Here is the code I have so far and I would have thought this would work.  This is C# .NET:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
{
    if (i.ToString().Length == 1)
    {
        i.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0');
    }

    Response.Write("Test: " + i);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Close, but you're just throwing the result away.

Comment: See, I don't like closing this while becaues the question was about the padding, the issue the OP was having had nothing to do with that, ironically he was doing that correct, he just wasn't assigning the value properly.

Comment: @CaffGeek the problem is no one with the same problem will ever see the right answer because the question is not asking right thing.  It probably could get salvaged to reask the proper question, but then you potentially invalidate at least 1 answer that didn't address the OP's real problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is `i` is still an integer, it needs to be assigned to a string

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
    {
        var iString = i.ToString();

        if(iString.Length == 1)
        {
            iString = iString.PadLeft(2,'0'); //RIGHT HERE!!!
        }
        Response.Write("Test: " + iString);
    }
```

However, much of this code is superflous, the `if` statement is not needed. Pad will only ped with zeroes up to the length (2) given. If it's already 2 or more characters long, it won't pad anything. All you need is this

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
    {
        var iString = i.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0');
        Response.Write("Test: " + iString);
    }
```

For that matter, the variable is no longer needed.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("Test: " + i.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0'));
    }
```

And if you'll be padding with zeroes all the time, and not some other character, you could just do this

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("Test: " + i.ToString("00"));
    }
```

And you should get into the habit of using `string.Format`

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("Test: {0}", i.ToString("00")));
    }
```

And to simplify the `string.Format` even further:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("Test: {0:00}", i));
    }
```

Answer (score 22):

You don't need IF, use ToString

```
int i = 5;

i.ToString("00"); //returns 05
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try with

```
var list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
{
    var result = string.Empty; 
    if(i < 10)
    {
         result = string.Format("0{0}", i);
    }
    else
    {
        result = i.ToString();
    }
    list.Add(result);
}
```

Nota : Concat your values nefore call Response.Redirect

Comment: Response.Redirect??? what are you talking about

Comment: @Tony  Yes i added this condition (i<10)

Comment: just concat his values before call Response.Redirect

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing anything with the following line:

```
i.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0');
```

`i` is still just an integer, and its string representation is not going to have a 0 in front of it when you use it later.
You would need to save a string of the value to print later.

Answer (score 3):

You needn't check `i.ToString().Length == 1`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)    
    Response.Write("Test: " + i.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0'));
```

Look to [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/92h5dc07.aspx) in MSDN for clarification. Common signature:

```
public string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
```

Also you can use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)    
    Response.Write("Test: " + i.ToString("00"));
```

Another way - use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
foreach (var number in Enumerable.Range(1, 36).Select(i => i.ToString("00")))
  Response.Write("Test: " + number);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're simply converting i to string and throwing away the result.
In `Response.Write("Test: " + i);` you're printing i instead of its conversion to string.
Try:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
{
    if (i.ToString().Length == 1)
    {
           Response.Write(i.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0'));
    }
}
```